# how to store image in longblob datatype of mysql using php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am working on a web application in PHP. I have the following HTML form:

```
<form action="addHotelDetails.php?action=<?php echo md5("check"); ?>" method="post" name="myform" id="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" border="0">
<tr>
<td align="right" width="35%" valign="top">Hotel Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="hotel_name"  style="border:#666633 1px solid;background:none;" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['hotel_name'])) print $_POST['hotel_name']; ?>"  size="20" maxlength="40"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td align="right" valign="top">City</td>
<td><input type="text" name="city" style="border:#666633 1px solid;background:none;" size="15" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['city'])) print $_POST['city']; ?>" maxlength="95"/>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="right" valign="top">State</td>
<td><input type="text" name="state" style="border:#666633 1px solid;background:none;" size="15" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['state'])) print $_POST['state']; ?>" maxlength="95"/>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="right" valign="top">Phone Number</td>
<td><input type="text" name="phone_no" style="border:#666633 1px solid;background:none;" size="12" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['phone_no'])) print $_POST['phone_no']; ?>" maxlength="95"/>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td align="right" valign="top">Email ID</td>
<td><input type="text" name="email_id" style="border:#666633 1px solid;background:none;" size="50" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['email_id'])) print $_POST['email_id']; ?>" maxlength="50" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right" valign="top">Image</td>
<form action="addHotelDetails.php"
method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<td><input type="file" name="image" style="border:#666633 1px solid;background:none;" size="20" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['image'])) print $_POST['image']; ?>" maxlength="50" />
</td>
</tr>
</form>
<tr>
<td align="right"></td>
<td>
<input type="hidden" name="frmname" value="add_new_hotel" />
<input type="submit" name="submit "value="Submit" style="width:100px; height:35px; font-size:16px;"/>
<input type="button" name="back" value="Back" onclick="parent.location='hotelList.php'" style="width:100px; height:35px; font-size:16px;"/>
<input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" style="width:100px; height:35px; font-size:16px;"/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Now i am able to send all the data to my database table but not able to send the image. I have an image field of longblob datatype. I want to browse an image from the computer and store the link in my table. I have written the following code in php to store the data. Please someone edit my code in php in order to store the image link in my table.

```
<?php
include_once "../dbconn.php";

if(isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action']==md5("check"))
{
    if(isset($_POST['frmname']) && $_POST['frmname']=='add_new_hotel')
{

      if(strlen(trim($_POST['hotel_name']))==0)
  print '<font style="color:#990000; padding-left: 120px">Please enter the Hotel name!!!</font>';
    else if(strlen(trim($_POST['city']))==0)
        print '<font style="color:#990000; padding-left: 120px">Please enter the city!!!</font>';
    else if(strlen(trim($_POST['state']))==0)
        print '<font style="color:#990000; padding-left: 120px">Please enter the state!!!</font>';
    else if(strlen(trim($_POST['phone_no']))==0)
        print '<font style="color:#990000; padding-left: 120px">Please enter the phone Number!!!</font>';
    else if(strlen(trim($_POST['email_id']))==0)
        print '<font style="color:#990000; padding-left: 120px">Please enter the email id!!!</font>';
    //else if(strlen(trim($_POST['image']))==0)
    //  print '<font style="color:#990000; padding-left: 120px">Please select an image!!!</font>';

    else    
    {   

        $hotel_name = $_POST['hotel_name']; 
        $city = $_POST['city'];
        $state = $_POST['state'];
        $phone_no = $_POST['phone_no']; 
        $email_id = $_POST['email_id']; 
        $image = $_POST['image']; 

        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');


        $sql = "INSERT INTO `hotel_details` (`hotel_name`, `city`, `state`, `phone_no`, `email_id`,`image`)
         VALUES ('$hotel_name', '$city','$state','$phone_no', '$email_id', $image) ";
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

        if(!$result) {
            print '<font style="color:#990000">Your query not saved. Please try again!!!</font>';
        }
        header("location: hotelList.php?");

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Why do you want to store the image in the DB to begin with? Probably 99 times out of 100, when a beginning programmer wants to do this, it is a bad idea. Consider just storing a file path or URL reference to where the file is uploaded instead. Also please do not use deprecated mysql_* functions and read up on SQL injection, as you currently have very insecure code.

Comment: You will need to catch the file with the $_FILES variable in PHP.

Comment: @MikeBrant ok if i store the image link will i able to view that image? can you please make the necessary changes in my php code to store the image path in the db?

Comment: As long as you put the file in a web-accessible directory, then it show be able to be viewed. The file path is just a string. Insert that string in the database, and output it in an img tags src attribute when you want to display the images on the page. Btw if you are following some book or tutorial, you REALLY should seek out a more modern resource, as even you HTML is really ancient in style and not compliant with modern web standards.

Comment: This question has been asked before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23435714/how-to-insert-an-image-in-database-from-php.  I would suggest you look over [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) where it is explained how files are uploaded. The idea is that you copy the file to a folder and then write the link to the image file into the database.

Answer (score 0):

Standard way is store the image in server folder and save the link to database. because in this case we can perform further operation on image. and to save image in longblob, its a lengthy process and take more time to normal save.